# How to remove SQL Server instances when there's no installation wizard opening up?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have installed the Developer edition of SQL Server 2017. Though I followed all the instructions for installation, I had a failure in installation at the end.

So, I uninstalled all the components of the server. When I'm uninstalling the components, it doesn't show the wizard in which I can uninstall instances.

Any help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say *i uninstalled all the components of the server*? By server you meant the actual server, or SQL Server? It's very likely that SQL Server has already been uninstalled by you, or rolled back since the installation failed.

Comment: When i installed the SQL server 2017, it had installed other components too. So, I uninstalled all of those one-by-one. According to the microsoft, when i click on unistall option for SQL server 2017, it is supposed to show the uninstallation wizard, where i should be able to remove the instances. But, no such wizard showed up when i uninstalled it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get exact installation you've used for your SQL Server and run following command:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=UNINSTALL
```

Keep in mind, it must be exactly same version/release etc.

Or you can try to delete all components manually, but in that case you'll still have some trash in the registry.